# Change image source at run time

Tags: apache-flex

I want to change the image at click event.I change the source of the image on click but its not reflecting immediately it comes when any other event is fired.Why is it so and anyone have the solution??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `image.validateNow()` after setting the `source` to force the change immediately.

Answer (score 2):

If you are setting the source to a url (such as `image.source = "/assets/myimage.jpg"`), then it could take 1+ frames to load the image since it is making an asynchronous URLRequest, so the change wouldn't be registered immediately.  Calling `validateNow()` wouldn't help in that case.

If you need it to load immediately, either embed the images (if they're small enough) or load a few of them at a time and store them somewhere, and set the image source to the bitmap (something like `image.source = myImageCache.getBitmap(0);`).

Hope that helps,
Lance

Answer (score 1):

Try a simple trick. Just add two image components take one's visibility true and other's visibility false. After click event just change the visibility of the image components. You will get the desired result.

This is demo, hope you'll like this.

```
<fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

private var isPause:Boolean=false;

protected function music_control1(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                if(!isPause)
                {
                    pos =_channel.position;
                    isPause=true;
                    SoundMixer.stopAll();
                    music2.visible=true;
                    music.visible=false;
                }
                else
                {
                    music.enabled=true;
                    _channel=_sound.play();
                    isPause=false;
                    music2.visible=false;
                    music.visible=true;
                }

            }
]]>
    </fx:Script>


    <s:Image id="music" x="200" y="245" click="music_control1(event)"
                     source="@Embed('assets/pause.png')"/>      
            <s:Image id="music2" x="200" y="245" click="music_control1(event)" visible="false"
                     source="@Embed('assets/play.png')"/>
```